# Google apps service - Cache service missing entries

Tags: javascript, caching, google-apps-script

I am using Google Apps Script code below.  The script ran without any errors. But I've discovered that some entries are missing.  The data has been cleaned up so no entries have control chars.  Is there size limitation of Cache object populated through putAll method?.  It works fine if i do individual put method.  But It takes too long to run  that way.  Using putAll takes only 1 - 2 minutes. Please help I've spent days to figure out this issue.  I am 100% positive there is nothing wrong with the data.  THANKS

```
//my data file looks like below with 180K entries. 
//Each line is terminated with \n
//{
// "0000000001": "Seattle",
// "0000000002": "Portland",
// "0000000006": "Tukwila",
// "0000000008": "Kirkland",
// ....
// }

var jsonString = DriveApp.getFileById("xxxxxx....xxx").getAs(MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT).getDataAsString();

var jsonObject = eval("(" + jsonString +")");

vendorCache.putAll(jsonObject, 21600); // 21600 cache it for 6 hours
```

Comment: Can you provide some cases that do not get put into the cache? Are they always the same ones? What happens if you try to put just those?

Comment: The following is 1 record that I noticed - consistently through putAll: "0000000170": "E Canada Dry DO NOT USE",   No issue with put method. It's 101th record in the file.  If I cut the number of lines to 172560 entries I see the record. But if I do the whole file - 178K or so the 101th record disappear.  No error loading the whole file.

Comment: I did more testing and and got the file to the point when the cache started missing. I cut down the last entry text char by char.  I checked the file size it's 6149564 bytes. It's about 6MB. So it must be some hard coded limit on the putAll method. I don't think the Cache size limit. Can somebody take a look at the code at the putAll method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**But if I do the whole file - 178K or so the 101th record disappear.**

This may be happening because looking at the [putAll(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache#putallvalues) states that the putAll method has a 100KB limit:

> **putAll(values)**
>
> The maximum length of a key is 250 characters. The maximum amount of
>   data that can be stored per key is 100KB. The values will expire from
>   the cache after 600 seconds (10 minutes).

Comment: Your statement is correct for the key and the data for each key.  That's not my problem. My key is 10 chars and the data associated with the key is less than 100KB. As I said before was able to add up many entries ~ 150,0000+ with the total size of the file around 6 MB.  So if you look at the putAll method it takes an object and the duration of the cache. I think there is a limit on the object size but the reference doc does not tell us that. So I was asking Google team to check the implementation of the putAll method and see if there is hard limit in the code